# cURL error 7: Failed to connect to getcomposer.org port 1080: Connection refused

Tags: laravel, curl, web-crawler

I am using [dweidner/laravel-goutte](https://github.com/dweidner/laravel-goutte) github package to crawl one website data i install this package by using composer and set the provider and alias in config/app.php in my controller i try the code like

```
$crawler = Goutte::request('GET', 'http://www.q-manager.com/');
```

then it is showing me error like

> cURL error 7: Failed to connect to getcomposer.org port 1080: Connection refused (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using shared host it may cause this issue for you.

Comment: Because they limit some features for you, I experienced this issue.